What linux util/artifact can we use to replace the binding done by the deprecated /sbin/raw To a raw_LUN device ie./dev/sd1?
What linux util/artifact can we use to replace the binding done by the deprecated /sbin/raw To a raw_LUN device  ?
before :
raw /dev/raw/raw1 /dev/sd1
ln -s /dev/raw/raw1 A
Just by referencing "A" within APP we were able to work with /dev/sd1.
Now ?    How do we bind a nonFileobject to /dev/sd1 ?
neither  symbolic link nor /dev/loop work.
Thanks
loop device and symbolic links didn't work
